# Unexpected token < in JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Getting this following error

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at Function.parse [as parseJSON] ()** Any help is appreciated.

JS:

```
function sendAndReceiveData(requestData, callback) {
    console.log(requestData);
    return $.ajax({
        url: "Ajaxcalls.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: requestData,
        async: true,
        //data: JSON.stringify(data),
        //dataType: 'jsonp',
        //contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            //callback(data);
            callback($.parseJSON(data));
        },
        error: function () {
            console.error("Error in your Ajax call");
        }
    });

}
```

PHP:

```
  if (mysqli_query($link, $createOrderSql)) {
            $response['code'] = 1;
        } else {
            $response['code'] = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
        break;
```

The SQL is successful. But I'm not able to parse the response data in JS. I tried to stringify the / not parse the data. Didn't help.

Comment: Can you console.log(data) to see what is it your are receiving? -in the success callback-

Comment: agreed, instead of callback(data) try console.log(data), if you get something from that it is probably your callback function

Comment: Console.log(data) didn't return any data. I use the same function sendAndReceiveData to process other requests too and it seems to work fine.